# How can you use python to log pen pressure, stroke length and x,y coordinate using a Wacom tablet?

Tags: python, logging, photoshop, wacom

The google results return old posts and expired links. As a python user, what can I do to grab all these personal data when I am drawing a picture in photoshop? Are there relevant frameworks that I can use? I am completely baffled on where to even start.

Comment: Sounds like something to ask the manufacturer's Tech Support.

Comment: It is rather the question of the drivers and the underlying OS. For example, under Gentoo, if Wacom device drivers are included in the kernel and the X server is configured correctly, all the touch events are transformed to X events and can be successfully captured with Xinput, so it should be a pretty straightforward task using `python-xlib` bindings.

Comment: I use windows 10, I asked the same question on reddit and someone recommended Qt which I have no idea what that is, I haven't looked into it yet.